# One-to–Zero-or-One relationship, with self

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following entity:

```
public class Category
{
  public int ID { get; set; }    
  public int? ParentID { get; set; }
  public string Name{ get; set; }
  public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
}
```

to which I'm trying to define a relationship: a `Category` can optionally have a parent category.
I've already defined the primary key:

```
HasKey(m => m.ID);
```

I've read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx) example, which includes a One-to–Zero-or-One relationship, but I can't grasp exactly how `HasRequired` implies an entity is optional in a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think a side problem is also that you cannot reference the exact same class to itself as a parent in EF, what you can use is Projection in order to have different attributes for the same type.

HasOptional in the child reference has the same effect as saying I may have a parent or not

Answer (score 0):

In the example you quote a child has a `ParentId` which is both a primary key and a foreign key. That is OK when parent and child are different entities (and different database tables), but not when they are self referencing. `Category` would have to have an ID that's both primary and foreign. But a primary key should be unique, so there's literally no room for a 1:1 child that should share the same key.

What can you do? I think the only option is to map the association as 1:n and enforce a business rule that n can't be greater than 1. Note that this is not an EF restriction. There's just no conceivable relational database model to constrain a self referencing association to 1:1.

Comment: of course parent and child are different entities - ID is the primary key, and ParentID is the foreign key (to another entity's ID)

Comment: Yes, but in the example it says *The OfficeAssignment has the InstructorID property that is a primary key and a foreign key*. So it takes the PK of the parent and copies it as its own PK which is an FK at the same time. Obviously, this can not be done when both entities are stored in the same table.